# Need to drop multiple commits from pull request

Tags: git, git-branch, rebase

I accidentally created git branch B, while being on branch A. Then i created a pull request, where i saw, that all the commits from branch A were transfered on B branch. I need to delete all A commits from B branch \ pull request without closing a pull request.

Comment: So you are saying you wish you had branched B from `main` instead of from branch A? If so, rebase it. (It seems you already know this, since you've included `rebase` in your tags. So what's the question?)

Comment: And if you don't know how to rebase it, type `git help rebase` and read it. I linked the manual, but it's exactly the same documentation with nicer formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rebase `B` onto the correct starting point (ie, not `A`), and then push it again (with `--force` if necessary).

The first step is a `git rebase --onto X A B` (where `X` is whatever starting point `B` *should* have), exactly as covered in the [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

The second step is just repeating whatever `git push` you already used.